# Parsing string to datetime while accounting for AM/PM in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I am trying to parse a string in this format `"2018 - 07 - 07 04 - AM"`
to pandas datetime using strftime format. However, It seems to me the format doesn't recognize the difference between `AM` and `PM`.

Here is what I tried:

```
pd.to_datetime("2018 - 07 - 07 04 - PM", format='%Y - %m - %d %H - %p').timestamp()
Out[4]: 1530936000.0
pd.to_datetime("2018 - 07 - 07 04 - AM", format='%Y - %m - %d %H - %p').timestamp()
Out[5]: 1530936000.0
```

Notice how the `AM` and `PM` are different in the above two strings, yet the same timeStamp is returned.

Pandas version: 0.23.3

Python version: 3.5.4

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Since you're parsing a 12-hour time format, you will need `%I` instead of `%H`, otherwise the `%p` specifier has no effect.

```
pd.to_datetime("2018 - 07 - 07 04 - PM", format='%Y - %m - %d %I - %p')
Timestamp('2018-07-07 16:00:00')
```

This behaviour is documented in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime):

> When used with the `strptime()` function, the `%p` directive only affects
>   the output hour field if the `%I` directive is used to parse the hour.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got an error message when trying the proposed solutions:

```
 ValueError: unconverted data remains: PM
```

This was solved by setting the locale to `en_US`.