# pandas to_datetime convert 6PM to 18

Tags: pandas

is there a nice way to convert Series data, represented like 1PM or  11AM to 13 and 11 accordingly with `to_datetime` or similar (other, than `re`)

data:

```
series
1PM
11AM
2PM
6PM
6AM
```

desired output:

```
series
13
11
14
18
6
```

`pd.to_datetime(df['series'])`  gives the following error:

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 11:00:00
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing string to datetime while accounting for AM/PM in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51235708/parsing-string-to-datetime-while-accounting-for-am-pm-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide the format you want to use, with as format `%I%p`:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['series'], format='%I%p').dt.hour
```

The [**`.dt.hour`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html) will thus obtain the hour for that timestamp. This gives us:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'series': ['1PM', '11AM', '2PM', '6PM', '6AM']})
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['series'], format='%I%p').dt.hour
0    13
1    11
2    14
3    18
4     6
Name: series, dtype: int64
```