# What is the best possible method to encode a time variable?

Tags: python, pandas, encoding

I have time column in my dataset and it looks like this:

```
0    08:05:51 PM
1    08:06:11 PM
2    08:08:57 AM
3    08:09:08 PM
4    08:11:01 AM
```

I am trying to encode it, but failing to bring out a possible method.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime`?

Comment: Hey @AdityaDas  what would be your expected output with the above dataset example? What code have you tried and how is it different than your expected output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing string to datetime while accounting for AM/PM in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51235708/parsing-string-to-datetime-while-accounting-for-am-pm-in-pandas)

Comment: I do know that time is cyclic so I am not getting a clue of how to encode it, where both AM and PM are given.

Comment: What do you want it "encoded" as? Do you want a `datetime`? Or would you rather have a `timedelta` running from 0 to 24 hours?

Comment: I am trying for encoding to proceed with data pre-processing

Comment: I want a time delta

Comment: Then given that as your Series (call it `s`). `s = pd.to_datetime(s); s = s-s.dt.normalize()`

Comment: Will it solve the issue with parsing of AM and PM?

Comment: ok so now I have got it in 24hour format. so what can be the best possible step?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any code to show us what you have tried?
I'd suggest using pandas if you are not.

```
df['dates'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], format='%I:%M:%S %p')
```